# Should I use the weak or the strong form in this sentence for the word "as"?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, weak-forms

"Went straight up as if from a factory" <---- for the word "as" in this sentence should I say it like /æz/ or like /əz/ ?

Comment: "Weak"?  "Strong"? Where did **these** come from?

Comment: It depends on whether you're stressing "as", which will depend if you pause before it.

Answer (score 1):

Both [æz] with stress, and [əz] without stress, sound fine, to me (I'm a native English speaker).  But the stress does matter.  You can't stress the [əz] version and have it sound like normal American English (I can't say about other dialects).

I've used brackets for your examples instead of slashes, since the variation between the vowels [æz] and [əz] that you're asking about concerns phonetics, not phonemes, and by convention, slashes are used only for phonemic forms.  There is no phoneme /ə/ in English (though some might disagree with this).

Comment: Yes, except I'm not sure explicitly enunciating the /æz/ insteead of a schwa automatically implies *stressing* it. And I'm having trouble imagining a context where you might naturally place (heavy) stress on it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers,  In the SPE account, only some level (not necessarily high)  of stress can save [æz] from reduction.  Of course, not everyone agrees.  I do, though.

Comment: I had to look up [SPE = The Sound Pattern of English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sound_Pattern_of_English), and I must admit I was kinda relieved to see it flagged *This article may be too technical for most readers to understand* (it was mostly double Dutch to me! :) But I suppose what you're getting at is that from the linguist's more formal perspective, "stress" applies to a broader range of contexts than I (as a relative layman) would normally expect. I'm naturally inclined to always assume intonational stress means ***high** stress*, but it ain't necessarily so.

Comment: Apropos which, do you think it's even *possible* to place [high] stress on a schwa when used as the indefinite article? It seems a somewhat "odd" (but credible) usage to me - *I don't want [stressed schwa] thing - I want **the** thing*. But is it still a schwa, and would it still be transcribed as /ə/ in IPA?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, no, I don't think it's possible to have stress on schwa in American English (don't know about other dialects).  When English speakers try to stress [ə], they actually say [ʌ].  The two vowels are articulated quite differently, and they sound quite different.  There is no stressed [ə] in American English, even at a low level of stress.  I see it written, sometimes, but it's just wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, on the existence of non-primary stress, yes, the SPE treatment does concern lower stress levels.  This is not an innovation of SPE, though.  It elaborates a traditional analysis of American structuralist phonemics, which recognized at least 3 distinctive stress levels.

Comment: I'm UK SE, so the /ʌ/ in my ***hut*** is completely different to Northerners. Their version sounds like a much-shortened version of ***hoot*** to me, and most Americans seem to use a shortened version of ***hart***. But mostly I don't even notice these differences, because some "automated process" (in my Broca's area?) transparently collapses all the variants into "the same sound" for the purposes of deciding what *words* people are saying.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, yes, you don't normally notice non-phonemic differences, and there is no phoneme /ə/ (so please stop writing it).

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't trying to include myself among the "some" who disagree in the final sense of your answer (I'm well aware that relativelky speaking I know nothing of such matters). But in case anyone else ends up reading these comments, [here's a link to John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104224/) explaining things in a way that seems very clear to me *as I read the text*. I doubt I'll be able to remember which way round to use *phonetics* and *phonemics*, but hopefully I'll at least retain the fact of their being a distinction, and what the two basic categories are.

Comment: ...but I promise to stop writing /ə/, if you can just explain to me what if any distinction there is between, say, **/əz/** and **[əz]**

Comment: @FumbleFingers, mostly, linguists disagree about such a difference as /əz/ versus [əz].  I say this: they are phonetically identical, and /əz/ refers to an intended pronunciation, while [əz] refers to an actual pronunciation.  If they are the same, that just means someone said exactly what he intended.  If you propose /əz/ for English, in effect, you propose that English speakers intend to say /əz/, which could conceivably be true, in some language or other, but happens to be false for English.  A schwa is never an articulatory target in English.

Comment: I should qualify that.  Schwa is never an articulatory target unless you're Inspector Clouseau.