# Why do (usually conservative) Americans pronounce "conservative" with an /ɪ/ sound, like consyrvative?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I have noticed this mispronunciation in post-1980 America.

People who take a little pride in their conservatism are almost
intentionally pronouncing the word *conservative*¹ as if it were spelled
*consyrvative*².

Here the affected “y” in *consyrvative* is not an “eh”³  sound, it’s like
the “y”⁴  in the word *Pyrrhic*⁵.

It’s observable in both public (e.g. Clint Eastwood) and non-public figures.

What is this all about?

Is it simply a bit of social posturing of the type that shows in England [when people say *Indiar* for *India* or *idear* for *idea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R#Linking_R)?

Or is there social signalling going on here, for example an ambitious man making a subtle pass at an obviously rich but conservatively dressed young woman?

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>The following footnoted technical pronunciation transcriptions contain [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) notation [for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English).  They are necessary so that we can talk about spoken sounds rather than about written letters, and so that they can be understood by an international audience and by native speakers whose native pronunciations differ subtly from one another’s.</sup>

1. *conservative*: [phonemic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104224/what-is-the-difference-between-phonetic-and-phonemic) /kənˈsərvətɪv/, /kənˈsɚvətəv/;
                   [phonetic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104224/what-is-the-difference-between-phonetic-and-phonemic) [kʰənˈsɚvət̬ɨv], [kʰn̩ˈsɹ̩vədəv].
2. *consyrvative*: phonemic /kənˈsirvətɪv/, /kənˈsɪrvətəv/;
                   phonetic [kʰənˈsɪɹvət̬ɨv], [kʰn̩ˈsiɹvədəv].
3. “eh” + R: phonemic /ər/, /ɚ/;
                   phonetic [əɹ], [ɚ], [ɹ̩] of [NURSE, SIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Nurse_mergers)
                    — *not* the phonemic and phonetic /ɛ/, [ɛ] of DRESS, PET.
4. “y” + R: phonemic /ir/ or /ɪr/;
                   phonetic [iɹ] or [ɪɹ] of [MIRROR, NEARER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#Mirror%E2%80%93nearer_and_/%CA%8Ar/%E2%80%93/u%CB%90r/_mergers).
5. *Pyrrhic*: phonemic /ˈpɪrɪk/ /ˈpirək/;
                   phonetic /ˈpʰɪɹɪk/, /ˈpʰiɹək/.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151480/discussion-on-question-by-trunk-why-do-usually-conservative-americans-pronounc); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Can you say what dialect you heard that in? (Like: Boston upper class, Midwestern working class, whatever.)

Comment: @Maverick >>  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151480/discussion-on-question-by-trunk-why-do-usually-conservative-americans-pronounc

Comment: Are you hearing any kind of r-sound in "conservative"? In US English it's normally said with an r-coloured vowel /ɝ/, but are you getting /ɪ/ with no r-colouring, or with a separate /r/ like in "Pyrrhic" or what? And can you provide audio or video clips, contrasting the two pronunciations. (I don't know why several comments requesting clarification have been moved to chat, but I guess I'll take my chances.)

Comment: Of course I hear an **r** sound.

Comment: I find it physically difficult to move my tongue down in order to make "ser" sound like "sehr" instead of "sir".

Comment: Could you find an example of an American "mispronouncing" the expression *conservative figure* in [the 31 instances listed](https://youglish.com/pronounce/conservative%20figure/english/us?) in YouGlish. To me the American speakers pronounce the expression (ignoring the difference in accents) in the same way as BrEng speakers but I do have some impaired hearing, so I'm not the best judge.

Comment: Here is a list of thirteen British speakers saying ["a conservative estimate"](https://youglish.com/pronounce/%22a%20conservative%22%20estimate/english/uk?). I think, compared to American English speakers, I can hear a difference in *stress* rather than in pronunciation. But I wouldn't put my hand in the fire.

Comment: @Mari-Lou  Have a listen to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DGl-4gByV4 from 0:50 and hear his pronunciation of "conservative". Maybe not quite a **y** but not an **e** either.

Comment: Can you please say when Clint utters "conservative" I'm not interested in watching the whole thing. One last thing, if you cannot find any real life examples it's going to be hard convincing anyone that some Americans pronounce the "e" in conservative as  [i].

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, please listen from 0:50 on.